# Convert terminal vim colour scheme to gui

Tags: vim, macvim

I've recently switched from terminal Vim to MacVim, I have my own custom's colour scheme that I wrote for terminal Vim - it has no `guifg` or `guibg` references unfortunately.

Is there a simple plugin, web app or otherwise that I can use to convert the existing colour scheme to be used with MacVim?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool but you would already have your colorscheme ready by now if you did it manually.

Comment: I suppose that is true, haha! I was just curious, I've heard of similar gui to terminal converters so though the opposite might be an existing tool.